# Can you "reach" someone to a location?

Tags: british-english

In "proper" British English, can you "reach" someone to a location?

My mother in law keeps using the word "reach" as a synonym for "take" (or "transport"):

*"I'll reach you to the train station."*

It sounds incorrect to me, but she's adamant that the word "reach" is being used correctly. We're both native English speakers.

I can't find any information to support her (unless I'm mistaken):
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/reach
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/reach_2

The closest I could find was...

*"We live within (easy) reach of the station."*

Who's correct? :)

Comment: I think the only correct usage of reach similar to that would be 'You can reach me at the hotel' (implying call there) ie you are right...

Comment: In my time on this planet and from being educated in the UK I must say that I have never come across this phrase. It is just not correct. It is akin to the phrase "Please could you learn me to play snooker" IMHO

Comment: And how do you think your mother-in-law will react when presented with cast-iron evidence that she ain't speaking proper??

Comment: It would be useful to know which part of the world (or the UK) your mother-in-law hails from.

Answer (score 4):

That's definitely a very strange wording. I can't find anything that uses *reach* in the same way, but there are very close definitions from [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reach):

> **reach** (*verb*)
>   1.3 - (reach something down) Stretch upwards to pick something up and bring it to a lower level
>   *She reached down a plate from the cupboard*.

Using this definition, it is possible to make your mother-in-law's wording seem correct if you stretch the meaning.

If you were to say *I'm going **down** to the train station*, you're metaphorically placing the train station under you and to go to the station, you have to physically go downwards. In this sense, the definition above could work because she's bringing you to a "lower level." Aside from this, I'm afraid it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

To my British English ears, this sounds odd, though the meaning is clear. 'Can you take me to the station' is what I'd expect to hear, but some IRish people will say 'Will you bring me to the station' - which implies to me that I am already there, and being asked to come and collect them. I have more of a problem with train station; I won't pretend I've never heard it, but 'station' alone or 'railway station' sound more natural to me.